# SSE in Jersey: Could not find a suitable constructor in javax.ws.rs.sse.Sse class

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, server-sent-events, grizzly

I am implementing Server Sent Events with Jersey 2.28 and I can't get the basic examples to work.

Other answers mention a dependency problem, I've added all the necessary dependencies to no avail:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I basically copy-pasted the example and ran it, I've tried variations found in tutorials such as https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-jax-rs-sse but it just won't work

```
    @GET
    @Path("/locations")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void getServerSentEvents(@Context SseEventSink eventSink, @Context Sse sse) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                final OutboundSseEvent event = sse.newEventBuilder().name("message-to-client")
                        .data(String.class, "Hello world " + i + "!").build();
                eventSink.send(event);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Can anyone provide me with the correct implementation for basic SSE using Jersey (I'm using the grizzly implementation)